# What is the name for creating sounds using Synthesizers

Tags: sound-effects

I'm trying to find stuff relating to creating sound effects with synthesizers, but I keep getting stuff like music creation.  What do you call sound creation which is specifically creating sounds with tools like vocoders, flangers, noise etc?

For instance, Transformers creates Soundwaves voice using a vocoder.  I'm hoping to learn more about how to do stuff like this by google searches.

Comment: You tagged this question with the ‘sound design’ tag, but have you tried searching based on that?

Comment: Sound Design is unneeded on this site, as it is all about sound design :-) Why not google for sound effects? Or sound effect synthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's video game and film sound design you're looking for :)

I suggest checking DesigningSound.org and [www.asoundeffect.com](http://www.asoundeffect.com) articles/blog posts.

Soundworkscollection.com is cool as well, they have videos from hollywood, less in depth compared to the articles from the other 2 sites but fun nonetheless.

Comment: thnx, will look into it.  =)